# Asynchronous Javascript Include Canceled by Chrome

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, http

I am loading an external javascript file and chrome intermittently cancels the request. It seems to depend on page load timing. Here is the net-internals log for the request:

```
263805: URL_REQUEST
https://s3.amazonaws.com/rejoiner/js/v3/rejoiner.lib.js?1446069887318&lv=1
Start Time: 2015-10-28 08:57:09.590

t=18003 [st= 0] +REQUEST_ALIVE  [dt=48]
t=18003 [st= 0]    URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=0]
t=18003 [st= 0]   +URL_REQUEST_START_JOB  [dt=48]
                   --> load_flags = 8448 (REPORT_RAW_HEADERS | VERIFY_EV_CERT)
                   --> method = "GET"
                   --> priority = "LOWEST"
                   --> url = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/rejoiner/js/v3/rejoiner.lib.js?1446069887318&lv=1"
t=18003 [st= 0]      URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=0]
t=18003 [st= 0]      HTTP_CACHE_GET_BACKEND  [dt=0]
t=18003 [st= 0]      HTTP_CACHE_OPEN_ENTRY  [dt=0]
                     --> net_error = -2 (ERR_FAILED)
t=18003 [st= 0]      HTTP_CACHE_CREATE_ENTRY  [dt=0]
t=18003 [st= 0]      HTTP_CACHE_ADD_TO_ENTRY  [dt=0]
t=18003 [st= 0]      URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=0]
t=18003 [st= 0]     +HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST  [dt=48]
t=18003 [st= 0]        HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST_STARTED_JOB
                       --> source_dependency = 263807 (HTTP_STREAM_JOB)
t=18051 [st=48]        CANCELLED
t=18051 [st=48]     -HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST
t=18051 [st=48]   -URL_REQUEST_START_JOB
                   --> net_error = -3 (ERR_ABORTED)
t=18051 [st=48]    URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=0]
t=18051 [st=48] -REQUEST_ALIVE
```

Here is the same request when it succeeds:

```
t=24000 [st=  0] +REQUEST_ALIVE  [dt=126]
t=24000 [st=  0]    URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=0]
t=24000 [st=  0]   +URL_REQUEST_START_JOB  [dt=125]
                    --> load_flags = 73984 (MAYBE_USER_GESTURE | REPORT_RAW_HEADERS | VERIFY_EV_CERT)
                    --> method = "GET"
                    --> priority = "LOWEST"
                    --> url = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/rejoiner/js/v3/rejoiner.lib.js?1446069893050&lv=1"
t=24000 [st=  0]      URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=0]
t=24000 [st=  0]      HTTP_CACHE_GET_BACKEND  [dt=0]
t=24000 [st=  0]      HTTP_CACHE_OPEN_ENTRY  [dt=0]
                      --> net_error = -2 (ERR_FAILED)
t=24000 [st=  0]      HTTP_CACHE_CREATE_ENTRY  [dt=0]
t=24000 [st=  0]      HTTP_CACHE_ADD_TO_ENTRY  [dt=0]
t=24000 [st=  0]      URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=0]
t=24000 [st=  0]     +HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST  [dt=1]
t=24000 [st=  0]        HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST_STARTED_JOB
                        --> source_dependency = 264331 (HTTP_STREAM_JOB)
t=24001 [st=  1]        HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST_BOUND_TO_JOB
                        --> source_dependency = 264331 (HTTP_STREAM_JOB)
t=24001 [st=  1]     -HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST
t=24001 [st=  1]     +HTTP_TRANSACTION_SEND_REQUEST  [dt=0]
t=24001 [st=  1]        HTTP_TRANSACTION_SEND_REQUEST_HEADERS
                        --> GET /rejoiner/js/v3/rejoiner.lib.js?1446069893050&lv=1 HTTP/1.1
                            Host: s3.amazonaws.com
                            Connection: keep-alive
                            Accept: */*
                            User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36
                            Referer: https://us.magnumboots.com/checkout/onepage/
                            Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
                            Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
t=24001 [st=  1]     -HTTP_TRANSACTION_SEND_REQUEST
t=24001 [st=  1]     +HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_HEADERS  [dt=124]
t=24001 [st=  1]        HTTP_STREAM_PARSER_READ_HEADERS  [dt=123]
t=24124 [st=124]        HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_RESPONSE_HEADERS
                        --> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                            x-amz-id-2: 5OJWFBfGFHJGBw61YC9pSNYojDhSWuMpR8NZcXptD3kiDuTVm83w0f8x2jxtlFgMUqhclTIwoJo=
                            x-amz-request-id: 3F7017076FECD8B3
                            Date: Wed, 28 Oct 2015 22:04:53 GMT
                            Last-Modified: Tue, 10 Mar 2015 13:41:46 GMT
                            ETag: "a6a68a146b39c4caf1c4dca4cf906c2f"
                            Accept-Ranges: bytes
                            Content-Type: application/x-javascript
                            Content-Length: 9541
                            Server: AmazonS3
t=24125 [st=125]     -HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_HEADERS
t=24125 [st=125]      HTTP_CACHE_WRITE_INFO  [dt=0]
t=24125 [st=125]      HTTP_CACHE_WRITE_DATA  [dt=0]
t=24125 [st=125]      HTTP_CACHE_WRITE_INFO  [dt=0]
t=24125 [st=125]      URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=0]
t=24125 [st=125]   -URL_REQUEST_START_JOB
t=24125 [st=125]    URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=0]
t=24125 [st=125]    HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_BODY  [dt=1]
t=24126 [st=126]    HTTP_CACHE_WRITE_DATA  [dt=0]
t=24126 [st=126]    URL_REQUEST_JOB_BYTES_READ
                    --> byte_count = 9541
t=24126 [st=126]    HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_BODY  [dt=0]
t=24126 [st=126]    HTTP_CACHE_WRITE_DATA  [dt=0]
t=24126 [st=126] -REQUEST_ALIVE
```

Any help or thoughts would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Can you create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I am asking how to interpret these logs, so I think the logs themselves are a complete and verifiable example.

Comment: If there is specific contex I can provide, please let me know. Given that the technical issue is intermittent and timing related it's very difficult to recreate.

Comment: How are you loading this external JavaScript file?  How frequently/what percentage of the time is the request cancelled?  What version of Chrome are you using, are the developer tools open, and is "Disable cache (while DevTools is open)" enabled?  Also, it may help to copy the webpage where you are seeing this issue and incrementally remove code from the copy until you are no longer able to reproduce the issue.  This may help isolate the cause of the request cancellation.